# Set max number of items returned via Content Query or list

Tags: 2010, list, content-query-web-part

Any ideas if this can be done?

I want to restrict the number of items returned to 5. Not sure if I can do this somehow at the CQWP or list level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A screenshot for SP 2010 may say more than 1000 words in the linked article about SP 2007.

[image]

Comment: It would be great though if there was a way to have a "show more" link.

Answer (score 0):

See the **Item Limit property** in the **Grouping and Sorting section**. [MSDN article reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff380147%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

You can also use [this 3rd party web part](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/sharepoint-2010-content-query-web-part-paging/) to add paging and set the number of items per page.